# rules for workbench moderation

Tags: rules, workbench

Using rules and workbench moderation, i need to send email to the author when the moderation state on his new article is changed to published.

But emails are sent every time i change the moderation state for every single revision. can someone please help me solve it.

Comment: What values are you using for *Event*, *Condition*, and *Action* currently for your rule?

Comment: Event: After saving new content (also tried after moderation transition)       Conditons: Content is using workbench moderation and contents current moderation state. Actions: send mail node:author:mail (that the new content has been moderated and published)